# Is Timatic the only database that airlines use to check documentation requirements for passengers?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, online-resources, timatic

Is [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) the only database that airlines use to check documentation requirements for passengers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two main systems used by airlines to check travel documentation requirements such as visas/etc.

The first of these is Timatic as you've mentioned.  This is by far the most popular, and is used by most airlines.

The second is [TravelDoc from ICTS](http://www.ictseurope.com/products/aviation-security/traveldoc) which provides a similar service, but is less common.